# replace line code not working java

Tags: java, io

I have a javascript which I need to edit using java so in the line 15 I have var=12.0001 and I want to replace it with some other value so i used this code

```
FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("D://maps2.html");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
br.readLine();
String lineIWant = br.readLine();
lineIWant=lineIWant.substring
System.out.println(lineIWant);
String line;String input = "";
System.getProperty("line.separator");
//the replace code
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) input += line + "\r\n";
System.out.println(input);
input = input.replace(lineIWant, "15.0001"); 
br.close();
```

so the problem with this is that it does get the lineIwant string correctly() but when I run it, it deletes the first 16 line of the file. When I pass the value ie "12.0001" in replace function instead of lineIWant it works correctly.

Comment: Please fix your indentation, tell us what's in your file, and ask a question. For example, what is `lineIWant=lineIWant.substring` supposed to do?

Comment: The first `for` iterates the first 15 lines and the following `String lineIWant = br.readLine();` reads the 16th line so you end up in the `while` starting from the 17th line

Comment: @ElliottFrisch lineIwant will be var lat=12.0001 I just wanted the value so i did a substring and i got 12.0001 correctly

Comment: @alfasin so what is the solution for this??

Comment: @PrateekSaxena You got 12.0001 correctly? Fantastic. *What is your **question***? When you say *what is the solution for this??*, to what do you refer?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch.. replace line code and the find line code works ok independently but when i pass value from find line code to replace line code it deletes first 16 lines.

Comment: @PrateekSaxena I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're trying to ask. You throw away the first 15 lines and the line separator. Your indentation is terrible, and you **still** haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop is redundant, try:

```
FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("D://maps2.html");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
String line;String input = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    
    input += line + "\r\n";
}
System.out.println(input);
input = input.replace("12.0001", "15.0001"); // simply replace the value you want 
br.close();
```